# Socketserver multiprocessing.Process is starting without calling start()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, raspberry-pi, socketserver

I have a problem with a Python script on my rpi. If I create a process object, it starts automatically and blocks everything else. I want it to run in the background, and to be able to start it by calling the `start()` method.

network_manager.py:

```
import socketserver

class NetworkManagerHandler(socketserver.StreamRequestHandler):
    def handle(self):
        print("Got some Data!")

class NetworkManagerServer(socketserver.ForkingMixIn, socketserver.TCPServer):
    pass
```

core.py:

```
import multiprocessing
from network_manager import NetworkManagerServer, NetworkManagerHandler

HOST, PORT = "100.0.0.1", 11891

network_manager = NetworkManagerServer((HOST, PORT), NetworkManagerHandler)
network_manager_process = 
            multiprocessing.Process(target=network_manager.serve_forever())
# !-> Program is blocking here, but the Server is working. <-! 
network_manager_process.daemon = True
network_manager_process.start()

print("Networkmanager is running. (%s:%s)" % (HOST, PORT))

# network_manager.shutdown()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
network_manager_process = 
            multiprocessing.Process(target=network_manager.serve_forever())
```

Should be this:

```
network_manager_process = 
            multiprocessing.Process(target=network_manager.serve_forever)
```

You don't actually want to call `serve_forever`, you just want to pass the function to the `Process` object.